# ColdFusion: structFind failing but key appears to be correct

Tags: struct, null, coldfusion

I can't figure out why my find is not working.

I have a structure created from deserializing some JSON. I get the key list from the structure and then try to find each value. 2 of the keys from the key list don't seem to exist.

The replace function is because I had to replace the %22 character encodings with ~ because it kept getting decoded midflight. That replace is just to put the double quotes back.

```
<cfscript>
    jsonIn = deserializeJSON(replace(result,"~","""","all"));
    typeList = "";
    for(x=1;x lte listLen(structKeyList(jsonIn[1]));x++){listAppend(typeList,"VarChar");}
    result = queryNew(structKeyList(jsonIn[1]),"");
    for(row in jsonIn) {
        queryAddRow(result);
        writeDump(row);
        for(cell in structKeyList(row)) {
            writeOutput(cell & " found: " & structKeyExists(row,cell) & "<br/>");
            //querySetCell(result, cell, row.find(cell));
        }
    }
writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

This is what I see in output:

[image: diagnostic display]

If I do a compare in those two cases I get a "-1", but I can't see why the strings are different (or how they can be since both are recovered by pulling from the key list of the object.)

**EDIT**

The error message is misleading. The problem is in the "undefined" values for those two keys. Changing the json "null" to space solved it.

Comment: I think I see the issue. I suddenly notice that the VALUES are undefined for those two keys.  I can't answer my own questions (low points) but I'll update with my solution.

Comment: Hint for next time: include the actual source data that demonstrates the issue, so we can lift-and-shift the code to our own environment to run it. These are handy reads: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, http://sscce.org/

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to `null` in ColdFusion. Let me explain why a key **does** and **does not** exist.

## NULL in Query

First of all, let's see why many developers new to CFML are confused. One of the first things you learn is:

```
<cfquery>
    SELECT NULL AS cellWithNull;
</cfquery>
```

will turn out as

[image: cfdump query]

### Reason

ColdFusion has no native support for `NULL` and will treat this value as an empty string.

## null in Java

At some point, you might need to pass a real `null` value to a Java method.

```
// Java
x = new org.example.FooBar();
x.someMethod(null);
```

Yet if you try to use or define a variable with null in CFML, such as:

```
y = null;
```

ColdFusion will throw an exception: `Variable NULL is undefined.`

### Reason

ColdFusion has no native support for `null`. In fact, it does not even recognize `null` and will attempt to resolve it as a variable by name instead.

```
// this will work
null = "";
y = null;
// y = [empty string]
```

### Solution

```
// ColdFusion
x = createObject("java", "org.example.FooBar").init();
x.someMethod(javaCast("null", ""));
```

[`javaCast("null", "")`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-in-k/javacast.html) exists for this use case. (The second argument has no meaning btw.)

## null in JSON (object)

```
x = deserializeJSON('{ "key": null }');
```

will turn out as

[image: cfdump json-object]

### Reason

ColdFusion has no native support for ... wait, what? Exactly, when deserializing `null`, the value will be treated as `undefined`, making the key to the value exist and not exist at the same time.

```
structKeyList(x)
>> "key"

structKeyArray(x)
>> [ "key" ]

structKeyExists(x, "key")
>> false

isNull(x.key)
>> true

isNull(x["key"])
>> true

x.key
>> Exception: Element KEY is undefined in X.

writeDump(x["key"])
>> undefined

writeOutput(x["key"])
>> [empty string]
```

### Solution

When iterating over keys of a struct, always check if the value behind the key is "defined" according to ColdFusion's standard. Use either `structKeyExists` or `isNull` to check the value.

## null in JSON (array)

```
x = deserializeJSON('[ null ]');
```

will turn out as

[image: cfdump json-array]

### Reason

You know the drill by now.

```
arrayLen(x)
>> 1

isNull(x[1])
>> Exception: Element 1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array.

writeDump(x[1])
>> Exception: Element 1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array.

writeOutput(x[1])
>> Exception: Element 1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array.

arrayIsDefined(x, 1)
>> false
```

### Solution

Always check with [arrayIsDefined](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arrayisdefined.html) before accessing an array index, if you expect the array to contain null values.

## ColdFusion functions without return value (void)

Not returning any value in a function, yet assigning the return to a variable will also turn out `undefined`.

```
function foo() { return; }

x = foo();
writeDump(x);
>> Exception: Variable X is undefined.
```

yet

```
x = { key: foo() };
writeDump(x);
```

[image: cfdump void]

## #JustColdFusionThings

It's worth noting that newer versions of ColdFusion (and [Lucee](https://www.lucee.org/) in general) support native null values. It still feels clunky working with them.

Comment: I realized that was the the issue. Thanks for providing a clear, comprehensive explanation.